# Mosquitto consume too much CPU and memroy paho clients

Tags: mosquitto, paho

I have been doing various tests with mosquitto and have noticed that it starts to consume 100% of the CPU and too much memory. I have tried to delete the `mosquitto.db` or
`mosquitto.log` files to see if that is what reloads and the problem clears up momentarily and then goes back to consuming excessive cpu and memory again.

Is there a reason why this happens? my clients are created in python 3.6 and I am using the Paho.mqtt library.
The broker is mosquitto v1.5.7 and it's in a raspberry pi3 B.

It should be noted that this did not happen to me before, it consumed a higher percentage of CPU and memory. Thanks in advance!!

the mosquitto configuration here:

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

listener 1883

log_type error
log_type notice
log_type information
log_type debug
log_type all
log_dest topic 
log_type warning

allow_anonymous false
connection_messages true

log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%d|%H:%M:%S

max_connections -1
message_size_limit 0
max_queued_messages 0
max_inflight_messages 0

password_file /etc/mosquitto/pwfile

####################################################
# MOSQUITTO LISTENER WITH SLL
####################################################

listener 8883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous false


#PARA BROKER EN RASPBERRY PI 3
#cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca_pi.crt
#keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server_pi.key
#certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server_pi.crt

tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Comment: This is not a valid Mosquitto configuration file. If you try to start Mosquitto with this file it should terminate with an error. `message_suze_limit` is not a valid config option.

Comment: What port is the client connecting on? What does the log file say? How many connections    is the broker getting at once (I mean actually counting them, not how many you expect)?

Comment: We really can't answer this question. Without some indication of what sort of load you are driving through the broker and what you changed between it being acceptable load and unacceptable.

Comment: clients are connected to port 1883. publishers send messages every 1 second.
both are executed at the same time. I modified the question and added the codes of the clients I am using. When I run 300 publishers and 75 subscribers the CPU percentage increases to 100% and the memory percentage starts to increase gradually reaching 79%. It should be noted that after clients disconnect, the %mem remains at 79%.

Comment: Each message has a payload of 70 bytes

Comment: This type of micro benchmark is meaningless it is 300 clients sending messages as fast as possible. Run something that actually represents your real work load.